# Angular Search multiple input values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-filter

I have a result set populated via ng-repeat. Now I need to do a sort of filtering. I tried using ng-filter to filter out search results. 
Use Case : User can enter multiple merchantIds each *comma separated*(or any other preffered machanism). And the result set populated corresponds to the merchantIds the user entered.
How currently works : Search works well when searching single merchantId. 
For example when user types merchantId, this list downs all merchants that starts with **merchantId**. When the input value is **merchantId_1**, the result is only related to merchantId_1. What I need is the user should be given the capability of typing **merchantId_1**, **merchantId_2** (each comma seperated) and list down the result corresponds to both merchantIds.

What is the feasible way of achieving this using Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a plunker that achieves what you were aiming for.

https://plnkr.co/edit/T9Z6GCFHzwH9xCKxkxJ7?p=preview

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="searchText" />
<div ng-repeat="merchant in merchants | merchantFilter:searchText">
  {{merchant}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.merchants = ['merchant_1', 'merchant_2', 'merchant_3']
})
.filter('merchantFilter', function() {
  return function(merchants, searchText) {
    // If there's no input, return full list
    if (!searchText) return merchants;
    // Split and trim the search string
    var searchTerms = searchText.split(',');
    searchTerms = searchTerms.map(function(term) {
      return term.trim();
    })
    // Filter and return merchants matching any search term
    var returnedArray = [];
    _.forEach(merchants, function(merchant) {
      if (_.find(searchTerms, function(term) {
        return merchant.indexOf(term) > -1;
      })) {
        returnedArray.push(merchant)
      }
    })
    return returnedArray;
  }
});
```

Comment: Fisso, this works like charm, Is there a way of improving this code, where we can use, angular autocomplete along with this :)